# Access SharePoint Online Rest API with Azure AD Authentication

Tags: c#, azure, rest, sharepoint, azure-active-directory

I am trying to access SharePoint online Rest API using Azure AD.

I have registered App in Azure AD and Granted full access as described in [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/309735/attempted-to-perform-an-unauthorized-operation-get-list-items-api-postman) Question

After Research, I came to know that I will be able to call SharePoint Rest APIs by Client ID and Certificate.

I uploaded an SSL Certificate along with my App in Azure AD.

Now I want to get That certificate and call SharePoint Rest Api.

I am using the following code to do that by following [this](https://laurakokkarinen.com/authenticating-to-office-365-apis-with-a-certificate-step-by-step/) Article:

```
  public OverduePOs GetItemDetail(string ItemID, string accessToken)
        {
            try
            {




                Uri uri = new Uri(MasterData.SiteURL);

                using (var client = new SPHttpClient(uri, MasterData.UserID, MasterData.PWD))
                {
                    var listTitle = "Overdue POs List";
                    var itemPayload = new { __metadata = new { type = "SP.Data.Overdue_x0020_POs_x0020_ListListItem" } };
                    var endpointUrl = string.Format("{0}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('{1}')/items({2})", uri, listTitle, ItemID);


                    var keyValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Authorization", "Bearer "+accessToken)
            };
                    CertificateAuthentication obj_cer = new CertificateAuthentication();
                  
                    HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(keyValues);


                  
                      var httpClient = new HttpClient();
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-ARR-ClientCert", obj_cer.GetCertificate(MasterData.clientId, "35E646884017E739A7B4F63675886FFB1CEF3C96").GetHashCode().ToString());

                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json"); // Specify JSON format
                    var response = httpClient.GetAsync(endpointUrl).Result;
                    var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OverduePOs>(result.ToString());
                    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OverduePOs>(result.ToString());
                }




            }
            catch (HttpRequestException ex)
            {

                return null;
            }

        }

 public class CertificateAuthentication
    {
        public ClientAssertionCertificate GetCertificate(string clientId, string thumbprint)
        {
            var certificate = GetCertificateFromStore(thumbprint);
            return new ClientAssertionCertificate(clientId, certificate);
        }
        //private static X509Certificate2 GetCertificateFromDirectory(string path, string password)
        //{
        //    return new X509Certificate2(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(path), password, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
        //}
        private static X509Certificate2 GetCertificateFromStore(string thumbprint)
        {
            var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            var certificates = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, false);
            store.Close();
            return certificates[0];
        }
    }
```

I have successfully got the Access Token but unable to get the certificate which is required to call SharePoint Rest API.

Can anyone Help me in this Please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note that, your code uses ***[Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/)*** library that is currently **deprecated** and no longer supported.
>
> Alternatively, you can use ***Microsoft.Identity.Client*** package for generating access token.

In my case, I performed **same steps** as you in registering application and adding permissions to it:

[image]

Now, I ran below PowerShell script from same [document](https://laurakokkarinen.com/authenticating-to-office-365-apis-with-a-certificate-step-by-step/) that created **certificates** with **`.cer`** and **`.pfx`** format in specified location:

```
$dnsName = "mxxxxxxx.sharepoint.com"
$password = "xxxxxxx"
$folderPath = "C:\temp\certs"
$fileName = "sricert17"
$yearsValid = 10

$certStoreLocation = "cert:\LocalMachine\My"
$expirationDate = (Get-Date).AddYears($yearsValid)
    
$certificate = New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName $dnsName -CertStoreLocation $certStoreLocation -NotAfter $expirationDate -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -KeySpec Signature    
$certificatePath = $certStoreLocation + '\' + $certificate.Thumbprint
$filePath = $folderPath + '\' + $fileName
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -Force -AsPlainText

Export-Certificate -Cert $certificatePath -FilePath ($filePath + '.cer')
Export-PfxCertificate -Cert $certificatePath -FilePath ($filePath + '.pfx') -Password $securePassword
```

**Response:**

[image]

I uploaded this **`.cer`** certificate in my Azure AD application like this:

[image]

When I ran below c# code to generate **access token** and called SharePoint Online Rest API, I got **response** successfully like this:

```cs
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main()
    {
        // Load the certificate from a file location
        X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2("C:/temp/certs/mycert17.pfx", "password");

        // Create the confidential client application object
        IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create("appId")
            .WithCertificate(certificate)
            .WithAuthority(new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId"))
            .Build();

        // Get the access token
        string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://mxxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/.default" };
        AuthenticationResult authResult = await confidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();

        // Print the access token
        Console.WriteLine("Access token: {0}\n", authResult.AccessToken);

        // Call SharePoint API using the access token
        await CallSharePointApi(authResult.AccessToken);
    }

    static async Task CallSharePointApi(string accessToken)
    {
        try
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri("https://mxxxxxxxxxx.sharepoint.com"); // SharePoint URL

            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                var listTitle = "srilist";
                var itemID = "1"; // Replace with the actual item ID
                var endpointUrl = $"{uri}/sites/sritestsite10/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('{listTitle}')/items({itemID})";

                // Set the required headers
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");

                var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(endpointUrl);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                // Process the SharePoint API response as needed
                Console.WriteLine("\nSharePoint API Response:\n" + result);
            }
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException ex)
        {
            // Handle or log the exception
            Console.WriteLine("Error calling SharePoint API: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: it is perfectly working in DEV Environment. we deployed the same at PRD and the following Exception came up: Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalClientException: Could not use the certificate for signing. See inner exception for details. Possible cause: this may be a known issue with apps build against .NET Deskt .

Comment: can you help in that?

Comment: Could you please post new question regarding this error with more details?

Comment: I have posted the details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77314156/could-not-use-the-certificate-for-signing-azure-app-connection-with-net